# Color specific characters?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a "Welcome message" with colors.

I'm trying to have a text like this and I would like the `$` characters to be white and all the `" | \ _ "` characters to be green

```
$$\   $$\                     
$$ |  $$ |                    
$$ |  $$ | $$$$$$\  $$\   $$\ 
$$$$$$$$ |$$  __$$\ $$ |  $$ |
$$  __$$ |$$$$$$$$ |$$ |  $$ |
$$ |  $$ |$$   ____|$$ |  $$ |
$$ |  $$ |\$$$$$$$\ \$$$$$$$ |
\__|  \__| \_______| \____$$ |
                    $$\   $$ |
                    \$$$$$$  |
                     \______/
```

So this is what I've got so far

```
import sys
class color:
   GREEN = '\033[92m'

print color.GREEN + """

$$\   $$\                     
$$ |  $$ |                    
$$ |  $$ | $$$$$$\  $$\   $$\ 
$$$$$$$$ |$$  __$$\ $$ |  $$ |
$$  __$$ |$$$$$$$$ |$$ |  $$ |
$$ |  $$ |$$   ____|$$ |  $$ |
$$ |  $$ |\$$$$$$$\ \$$$$$$$ |
\__|  \__| \_______| \____$$ |
                    $$\   $$ |
                    \$$$$$$  |
                     \______/ 
"""
```

The problem is it makes everything green because of the triple quotes, I want either the dollar signs or only the other characters around it | \ / _ -

Comment: You can use string.replace to replace `$` by `\033[92m$\033[0m`

Comment: I don't get it. You get all of your text in green because that is what you tell your code to do. If you want some parts to print in another color, just add that color at the correct place using the exact same syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `string.replace` to replace `$` by `\033[92m$\033[0m`

```
class color:
   GREEN = '\033[92m'
   BASE = '\033[0m'

print ("""

$$\   $$\                     
$$ |  $$ |                    
$$ |  $$ | $$$$$$\  $$\   $$\ 
$$$$$$$$ |$$  __$$\ $$ |  $$ |
$$  __$$ |$$$$$$$$ |$$ |  $$ |
$$ |  $$ |$$   ____|$$ |  $$ |
$$ |  $$ |\$$$$$$$\ \$$$$$$$ |
\__|  \__| \_______| \____$$ |
                    $$\   $$ |
                    \$$$$$$  |
                     \______/ 
""".replace('$', color.GREEN + '$' + color.BASE))
```

Comment: Thanks so much lovasoa! I was trying so many diffrent things yesterday and now I got anwser in just a few minutes! <3 Thanks again for the help.